# What is this perennial, mauve flowering herb?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials

I am trying to identify flowers by the photo I have. Everything I know is that they are:

- Perennial flowers
- Spring flowers
- Grow in Eastern Europe

I have been trying to find them using Google Pictures using different queries, but I did not find a good match.

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *Hepatica nobilis* (also *Anemone hepatica*). It grows on forests. An other name is *Hepatica triloba* because of the form on leaves.

[And there is also a *Vinca minor*]